# Is it possible that $\liminf=+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know $\liminf x_n$ is the infimum of the set of limits points $\mathcal{L}$, and is an extended real number i.e $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

If we have the sequence $$x_n=n~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ then } \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n=+\infty$$
And it is the only limit point in $x_n$ since any subsequence $x_{n_k}$ we take, will diverge to $+\infty$ (or converge to $+\infty$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$).

Then, $\liminf x_n=+\infty$. However, my mate told me that $\liminf$ can never be $+\infty$ and that $\limsup$ can never be $-\infty$, but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: your professor is wrong

Comment: I totally agree with @Masacroso !

Comment: I see no problem with what you are saying ($-\infty$ and any finite number are clearly be strictly less than the $\liminf$ in your example).  To me, a stranger result is that the minimum of an empty set is also $+\infty$

Comment: I agree with you all, thank you very much for clarifying my doubt :)

Comment: @Henry: the convention is that the infimum of the empty set is $-\infty$, because we want $\inf(A)$ to satisfy $(\forall a \in A( \inf(A) \le a)) \land (\forall x((\forall a \in A (x \le a)) \Rightarrow x \le \inf(A)))$, but $\forall a \in \emptyset(x \le a)$ is vacuously true, giving us that $\inf(\emptyset)$ has to be $-\infty$.

Comment: @RobArthan the convention I use is that we want $\inf(A \cup B) = \min\{\inf(A),\inf(B)\}$ so $\inf(\emptyset)=+\infty$ since anything else would not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with $\liminf x_n$ to be $+\infty$ since it is an extended real number.

Your example is correct. :D